# Почему функция CreateThread запускает функцию сразу после создания?

Tags: c, windows, многопоточность

возникла проблема с распараллеливанием вывода на экран консоли:

История: исполнение `WriteConsoleOutputW` занимает с каждым последующим обновлением занимает все больше времени, при чем размер буфера не меняется. Изначально была идея вынести вывод в отдельный поток, но оно все еще занимает 74-76 мс, что невероятно долго. Последнее что пришло в голову - разделить буфер на несколько частей и выводить их в нескольких потоках.

```
self->ThreadPool[0] = CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        &PassToRender1,
        self,
        0,
        &self->ThreadPoolID[0]);

    self->ThreadPool[1] = CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        &PassToRender2,
        self,
        0,
        &self->ThreadPoolID[1]);
```

```
void _OutputToScreen(struct Window *self)
{
    WaitForMultipleObjects(2, self->ThreadPool, true, INFINITE);
}

DWORD VTHREAD PassToRender1(struct Window *self)
{
    WriteConsoleOutputW(
        self->hOut, 
        *self->ppBuffer, 
        (COORD) { (short)self->Width, (short)self->Height/2 }, 
        (COORD) { 0, 0 }, 
        &self->rWindowRect
    );
}
DWORD VTHREAD PassToRender2(struct Window *self)
{
    SMALL_RECT rect = self->rWindowRect;
    rect.Top = rect.Bottom / 2;

    WriteConsoleOutputW(
        self->hOut,
        *self->ppBuffer,
        (COORD) { (short)self->Width, (short)self->Height/2 }, 
        (COORD) { 0, (short)self->Height / 2 }, 
        &rect
    );
}
```

Однако как я выяснил `CreateThread` запускает функции сразу после создания, а я бы хотел, чтобы я мог обращаться к потокам по вызову функций, при том не пересоздавая потоки, что дорого по времени.

Есть ли какие-нибудь варианты как сделать запуск по вызову?

Дополнение: Вот что я рендерю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> История: исполнение WriteConsoleOutputW занимает с каждым последующим обновлением занимает все больше времени, при чем размер буфера не меняется. Изначально была идея вынести вывод в отдельный поток, но оно все еще занимает 74-76 мс, что невероятно долго.

Хотелось бы увидеть, на каком размере буфера и в какой ОС вывод занимает так долго. У меня на Windows 10 при буфере 100х50 среднее время 0.1 - 0.2 мс, вот код для тестирования:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

const int W = 100; //ширина области рисования
const int H = 50; //высота области рисования
CHAR_INFO chiBuffer[W*H] = { 0 };
COORD coordBufSize;
COORD coordBufCoord;
HANDLE hStdout;
SMALL_RECT srctWriteRect;

void Render(int pos) {

    //рисуем звездочку в заданной позиции
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(chiBuffer) / sizeof(CHAR_INFO); i++) {
        chiBuffer[i].Attributes = FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE;

        if (i == pos) chiBuffer[i].Char.UnicodeChar = L'*';
        else chiBuffer[i].Char.UnicodeChar = L' ';
    }

    srctWriteRect.Top = 0;
    srctWriteRect.Left = 0;
    srctWriteRect.Bottom = H;
    srctWriteRect.Right = W;

    BOOL fSuccess = WriteConsoleOutputW(
        hStdout, // screen buffer to write to 
        chiBuffer,        // buffer to copy from 
        coordBufSize,     // col-row size of chiBuffer 
        coordBufCoord,    // top left src cell in chiBuffer 
        &srctWriteRect);  // dest. screen buffer rectangle  

    if (!fSuccess)
    {
        printf("WriteConsoleOutput failed - (%d)\n", GetLastError());       
    }   
}

int main(void)
{   
    BOOL fSuccess;  
        
    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    coordBufSize.Y = H;
    coordBufSize.X = W;
    coordBufCoord.X = 0;
    coordBufCoord.Y = 0;

    // Set the destination rectangle. 

    srctWriteRect.Top = 0;
    srctWriteRect.Left = 0;
    srctWriteRect.Bottom = H;
    srctWriteRect.Right = W;        

    const int N_RUNS = 50; //число запусков в пределах одного теста
    const int N_TESTS = 50; //число тестов
    float tsum = 0;
    DWORD t1;
    DWORD t2;

    Render(0);
    int pos = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < N_TESTS; i++) {

        t1 = GetTickCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < N_RUNS; j++) {
                        
            Render(pos);
            pos++;
            if (pos >= W * H)pos = 0;
        }
        t2 = GetTickCount();
        tsum += (t2 - t1)/(float)N_RUNS; //определим длительность отрисовки в пределах одного теста     
    }

    //выведем среднее время отрисовки   
    wchar_t s[100] = L"";       
    swprintf(s,100,L"Render time = %.3f ms\n", tsum / (float)N_TESTS);
    MessageBoxW(GetConsoleWindow(), s, L"Results", MB_OK);
    getchar();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Но я слышал, что на Windows 7 и ранее консоль рисует медленнее.

> Последнее что пришло в голову - разделить буфер на несколько частей и выводить их в нескольких потоках.

Идея распараллелить что-то с целью его ускорения редко является хорошей. Начать с того, что код может выполняться на компьютере с одним процессорным ядром, тогда "ускорение" в реальности обернется замедлением. Но даже если ядер несколько, реальный эффект от параллельности проявится только когда потоки не конкурируют за общие ресурсы. В случае консоли, я подозреваю, что там внутренне работает свой механизм синхронизации, и эффекта не будет.

> Однако как я выяснил CreateThread запускает функции сразу после создания

Это не совсем так. Есть флаг [CREATE_SUSPENDED](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread):

> The thread is created in a suspended state, and does not run until the ResumeThread function is called.

Но для вашей задачи это никак не поможет.

---

Реальная оптимизация, которая здесь могла бы помочь - это вместо вывода всего буфера проверять, какие области изменились, и выводить только их. Если на каждом шаге не весь экран изменяется, это может дать серьезное ускорение.

---

### Дополнение

Если попробовать на большом буфере и распараллелить вот так с синхронизацией через события:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

void Render1();
void Render2();

const int W = 640; //ширина области рисования
const int H = 320; //высота области рисования
CHAR_INFO chiBuffer[W*H] = { 0 };
HANDLE hStdout;

//первая часть
COORD coordBufSize1;
COORD coordBufCoord1;
SMALL_RECT srctWriteRect1;

//вторая часть
COORD coordBufSize2;
COORD coordBufCoord2;
SMALL_RECT srctWriteRect2;

//события для синхронизации
HANDLE evtRendering1;
HANDLE evtRendering2;
HANDLE evtRendered1;
HANDLE evtRendered2;

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc1(LPVOID lpThreadParameter) {
    while (1) {
        WaitForSingleObject(evtRendering1, INFINITE); //ждем сигнала
        ResetEvent(evtRendering1);

        //выводим первую половину
        Render1();

        //сообщаем о завершении
        SetEvent(evtRendered1);
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc2(LPVOID lpThreadParameter) {
    while (1) {
        WaitForSingleObject(evtRendering2, INFINITE); //ждем сигнала
        ResetEvent(evtRendering2);

        //выводим первую половину
        Render2();

        //сообщаем о завершении
        SetEvent(evtRendered2);
    }
}

void FillBuffer(int pos) {
    //рисуем звездочку в заданной позиции
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(chiBuffer) / sizeof(CHAR_INFO); i++) {
        chiBuffer[i].Attributes = FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE;

        if (i == pos) chiBuffer[i].Char.UnicodeChar = L'*';
        else chiBuffer[i].Char.UnicodeChar = L' ';
    }
}

void Render1() {            

    srctWriteRect1.Top = 0;
    srctWriteRect1.Left = 0;
    srctWriteRect1.Bottom = H/2;
    srctWriteRect1.Right = W;

    BOOL fSuccess = WriteConsoleOutputW(
        hStdout, // screen buffer to write to 
        chiBuffer,        // buffer to copy from 
        coordBufSize1,     // col-row size of chiBuffer 
        coordBufCoord1,    // top left src cell in chiBuffer 
        &srctWriteRect1);  // dest. screen buffer rectangle     
        
    if (!fSuccess)
    {
        printf("Render1: WriteConsoleOutput failed - (%d)\n", GetLastError());      
    }   
}

void Render2() {

    srctWriteRect2.Top = H / 2;
    srctWriteRect2.Left = 0;
    srctWriteRect2.Bottom = H;
    srctWriteRect2.Right = W;

    BOOL fSuccess = WriteConsoleOutputW(
        hStdout, // screen buffer to write to 
        &(chiBuffer[W*H/2]),        // buffer to copy from 
        coordBufSize2,     // col-row size of chiBuffer 
        coordBufCoord2,    // top left src cell in chiBuffer 
        &srctWriteRect2);  // dest. screen buffer rectangle     

    if (!fSuccess)
    {
        printf("Render2: WriteConsoleOutput failed - (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    }
}

void Render(BOOL parallel) {

    if (parallel != FALSE) {
        //запускаем оба потока
        SetEvent(evtRendering1);
        SetEvent(evtRendering2);

        HANDLE ha[2] = { evtRendered1,evtRendered2 };

        //ждем завершения вывода

        DWORD dwWaitResult = WaitForMultipleObjects(
            2,   // number of handles in array
            ha,     // array of handles
            TRUE,          // wait until all are signaled
            INFINITE);

        switch (dwWaitResult)
        {
            // All objects were signaled
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0: break;

            // An error occurred
            default:
            printf("WaitForMultipleObjects failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
            break;
        }

        ResetEvent(evtRendered1);
        ResetEvent(evtRendered2);
    }
    else {
        Render1();
        Render2();
    }
}

int main(void)
{   
    BOOL fSuccess;  
        
    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    coordBufSize1.Y = H/2;
    coordBufSize1.X = W;
    coordBufCoord1.X = 0;
    coordBufCoord1.Y = 0;

    coordBufSize2.Y = H / 2;
    coordBufSize2.X = W;
    coordBufCoord2.X = 0;
    coordBufCoord2.Y = 0/*H / 2*/;

    // Set the destination rectangle. 

    srctWriteRect1.Top = 0;
    srctWriteRect1.Left = 0;
    srctWriteRect1.Bottom = H/2;
    srctWriteRect1.Right = W;   

    srctWriteRect2.Top = H / 2;
    srctWriteRect2.Left = 0;
    srctWriteRect2.Bottom = H;
    srctWriteRect2.Right = W;
        
    const int N_TESTS = 500; //число тестов
    DWORD tsum = 0;
    DWORD t1;
    DWORD t2;

    evtRendering1 = CreateEvent(
        NULL,               // default security attributes
        TRUE,               // manual-reset event
        FALSE,              // initial state is nonsignaled
        TEXT("evtRendering1")  // object name
    );

    evtRendering2 = CreateEvent(
        NULL,               // default security attributes
        TRUE,               // manual-reset event
        FALSE,              // initial state is nonsignaled
        TEXT("evtRendering2")  // object name
    );

    evtRendered1 = CreateEvent(
        NULL,               // default security attributes
        TRUE,               // manual-reset event
        FALSE,              // initial state is nonsignaled
        TEXT("evtRendered1")  // object name
    );

    evtRendered2 = CreateEvent(
        NULL,               // default security attributes
        TRUE,               // manual-reset event
        FALSE,              // initial state is nonsignaled
        TEXT("evtRendered2")  // object name
    );

    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(
        NULL,              // default security
        0,                 // default stack size
        ThreadProc1,        // name of the thread function
        NULL,              // no thread parameters
        0,                 // default startup flags
        NULL);

    if (hThread == NULL)
    {
        printf("CreateThread failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    hThread = CreateThread(
        NULL,              // default security
        0,                 // default stack size
        ThreadProc2,        // name of the thread function
        NULL,              // no thread parameters
        0,                 // default startup flags
        NULL);

    if (hThread == NULL)
    {
        printf("CreateThread failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
        
    /* *** Начало теста *** */
    BOOL parallel = TRUE;
    FillBuffer(0);
    Render(parallel);
    int pos = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < N_TESTS; i++) {

        FillBuffer(pos);
        t1 = GetTickCount();                                
        Render(parallel);
        t2 = GetTickCount();
        pos++;
        if (pos >= W * H)pos = 0;
                
        tsum += (t2 - t1); //определим длительность отрисовки в пределах одного теста       
    }

    //выведем среднее время отрисовки   
    wchar_t s[100] = L"";       
    swprintf(s,100,L"Render time = %.3f ms\n", tsum / (float)N_TESTS);
    MessageBoxW(GetConsoleWindow(), s, L"Results", MB_OK);
    getchar();
    
    return 0;
}
```

То получается

- без параллельности: 1.2 мс
- с параллельностью: 1.6 мс

То есть вроде как пользы от распараллеливания нет, даже наоборот, получается медленнее за счет накладных расходов на ожидание.

Comment: Размер буфера 640:360, и менять сегменты не получится, ибо проще протолкнуть целый буфер, чем пытаться искать в текстурированной и освещенной 3Д модели одинаковые точки, версия Windows: 10.0.18362.418. Через дизассемблер я узнал что код сильно поменялся у этой функции, перед этим он шел через 7й системный вызов, сейчас через там какая-то магия с буферами

Comment: @IlyaPakhmutov ОК, с таким размером у меня занимает порядка 2 мс. Далеко до вашего, но хотя бы ощутимое время, чтобы поэкспериментировать. Добавил в ответ способ с параллельным выводом на двух потоках (у меня эффекта нет).

Comment: Только вот как вы выводите такой большой буфер? Монитор гигантский, или наоборот, шрифт в консоли специально установлен маленький?

Comment: Скорее всего вывод в консоль уже предусматривает однопоточное завладение дескриптором консоли, т.е. вы не можете в два потока писать в консоль одновременно, поэтому распаралеливание и не дает результа. *Монитор гиганский* - да да да. По-моему лучше писать в файл, если много инфы.

Comment: Обычное вывод в консоль и GUI не могут обеспечить высокой скорости рендеринга, если вы хотитите что б было как в фильме "Матрица" только в 10-20 раз быстрее - то лучше использовать OpenGL или DirectX. Но для вывода чисто текста, думаю обычного GUI с PolyTextOut вам хватит. http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vstudio/dd162821

Comment: Я тут вспомнил, у консоли есть параметр "к-во строк" Попробуйте установите этот параметр хотя бы в 50. Лучше в столько сколько видно на экране. Можно руцями - потом разберетесь как програмно. (По умолчанию он 300 и при повторном выводе много времени видимо уходит на скроллирование 300 строк). Кстати - в полноекранном режиме 300 не будет - и ускорение будет заметно. Попробуйте так же полноекранный режим.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight шрифт 2х2 пикселя + кастомная палитра, но это не должно так просаживать перформанс